# Flash Disk/USB - The disk structure is corrupt and unreadable

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I have a 32 GB USB flash drive and it's corrupted, the message it shows afterwards is: `The disk structure is corrupt and unreadable`. I tried to repair it with a software called `Mini Tool Partition Wizard` and it failed, it seems this tool works on internal and external hard disks.

How can I repair my USB Flash?

Comment: I'm pleased you received the help you needed, but this is (and was) not on-topic for Stack Overflow. This site is for programming questions. If you have questions about general software or hardware issues, the best Stack Exchange site to go to is _Super User_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Diskpart on Windows. Type `list disk`, select (`select disk ...`)  your USB and enter the commands : `clean`, `convert mbr`, `create partition primary`.

**Note that the "clean" command will delete all data on the device**, so this is a procedure to rescue the disk for future use, but not to preserve the data on the disk.

Comment: Man thanks so much for this amazing answer @Romaxin, you save my life

Comment: just to make this clear: the above commands (clean) will delete all data on the device, so this is a procedure to rescue the disk for future use, but not to preserve the data on the disk